# How to make the Turtlebot rotate in place a set # of degrees/radians

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked at the geometry_msgs::Twist class but that allows you to only set the velocity of a turn.  I want to make the turtlebot slowly rotate in place a set number of radians/degrees on command.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12557/how-to-make-the-turtlebot-rotate-in-place-a-set-#-of-degrees/radians/) by [guzza](https://answers.ros.org/users/374/guzza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Keep sending a `Twist` messages with your desired yaw rate (`angular.z` in radians/sec) until it reaches the desired heading. Then, start sending `Twist` with a zero yaw rate.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guzza](https://answers.ros.org/users/374/guzza/) on 2012-01-09**:
Thanks this worked out!

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-12**:
I have the same question. I wonder if it's possible to send the desired radian/degree as a parameter to the programme? So that when I run the script it automatically rotates a desired degree.

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-12**:
Maybe I didn't get your advice right, but how do I fixate the moment it reached the desired heading given that I set only the velocity?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-02-12**:
You need some feedback, probably from an Odometry message.

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-13**:
Thank you! I will try that.